# Create shortcut on home screen in Android O

Tags: java, android, shortcut, homescreen, android-8.0-oreo

Since Android O, using `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` is deprecated. In the previous versions I used this and it worked.

```
Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
```

but now this does not work any more. No home screen shortcut is created. How do I create a home screen shortcut in Android O? In source code it says `@deprecated Replaced with {@link android.content.pm.ShortcutManager#createShortcutResultIntent}`. So I tried this:

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
ShortcutInfo.Builder mShortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setShortLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setLongLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(mShortcutInfo.build());
```

I get error that shortcut intent must be provided:

```
10-17 23:08:00.305 13256-13256/com.audiorecorder.wel.voicerecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.wel.shortcut, PID: 13256
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wel.shortcut/com.wel.shortcut.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Shortcut Intent must be provided
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Shortcut Intent must be provided
                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1948)
                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
                                                                                     at android.content.pm.IShortcutService$Stub$Proxy.createShortcutResultIntent(IShortcutService.java:635)
                                                                                     at android.content.pm.ShortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(ShortcutManager.java:1043)
                                                                                     at voicerecorder.wel.audiorecorder.com.voicerecorder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Edit:
As suggested in ianhanniballake's answer I set intent and got `java.lang.NullPointerException: intent's action must be set` So I tried `new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT")`. The code runs but no shortcut is created.

Edit 2:
This is the code that I am running now but I do not see shortcut on homescreen.

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
ShortcutInfo.Builder mShortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setShortLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setLongLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfo.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
mShortcutInfo.setIntent(shortcutIntent);
sendBroadcast(shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(mShortcutInfo.build()));
```

Edit 3:

```
ShortcutInfo.Builder mShortcutInfoBuilder = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setShortLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setLongLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setIntent(shortcutIntent);
ShortcutInfo mShortcutInfo = mShortcutInfoBuilder.build();
ShortcutManager mShortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
mShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(mShortcutInfo, null);
```

This brings up the permission dialog as below:

[image: Permisison dialog]

but the problem is that it does not appear in the app foreground. It only appears after pressing the back key. It also does not appear on home key press.

Comment: Did you set permission?

Comment: Yes, `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />`

Comment: were you able to find a solution for creating a shortcut without showing a dialog on Android Oreo and above?

Answer (score 2):

add this at the end

```
shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut ( shortcutInfo ,  null )
```

and for shortcutInfo check to set unique Id

```
ShortcutInfo.Builder mShortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(MainActivity.this, **getString(R.string.Different_String)**);
```

Comment: please see the edit. I have added this but there is one problem.

Comment: @Ali there is restriction for shortcuts on android O. try to call finish onPause()

Comment: I don't want user to leave app

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use This Method

```
private void createShortcut() {
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
    shortcutManager = mContext.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (shortcutManager != null) {
        if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
            ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(mContext, uniqueid)    
                    .setShortLabel("Demo")
                    .setLongLabel("Open the Android Document")
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.andi))
                    .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com")))
                    .build();

            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcut, null);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Pinned shortcuts are not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

I am using this in my app but only one restriction it only creates Two shortcut at MAX
don't know why if any one found way to create more then please mention here..

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is ancient but it's among the first result when you google for the deprecation so I thought this might help others:

The person asking is setting a wrong intent in `setIntent` in Edit 3. You are supposed to specify an intent that is called when the short cut is pressed, not an `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT` intend. ianhanniballake already pointed this out.

A fix for edit 3 would look like this:

```
ShortcutInfo.Builder mShortcutInfoBuilder = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setShortLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setLongLabel(getString(R.string.app_name));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
mShortcutInfoBuilder.setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
ShortcutInfo mShortcutInfo = mShortcutInfoBuilder.build();
ShortcutManager mShortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
mShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(mShortcutInfo, null);
```

`createShortcutResultIntent` actually is for something very different, it's for when you want to get an callback function called when the creation of the pinned shortcut was successful.

Comment: you need to add action to your `Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class) `otherwise you will get exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [setIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutInfo.Builder.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent)):

```
mShortcutInfo.setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: I called setIntent(). Code runs but shortcut isn't created.

Comment: Important note: You must add an action on Intent or it will crash with: java.lang.NullPointerException: intent's action must be set